# How do you test an instance method in Python with assertRaises?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

I understand how to use `assertRaises` on a function or a lambda, but I wanted to use it on an instance method.

So for example, if I have a class `calculator` that does infinite precision arithmetic, I might write the test:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.calculator = calculator.calculator()

def test_add(self):
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.calculator.add, ['hello', 4])
```

Because `self.calculator.add` is callable and `['hello', 4]` are the arguments I would like to pass it, however, when I run the test I get the following fatal error:

```
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num2'
```

I believe it is throwing this error because when `self.assertRaises` is calling `self.calculator.add`, `self` isn't being passed as the first arugment like it generally is when an instance method is called. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the other answers said you must pass the values separately, but an alternative which you may find reads more easily is to use the `with` statement:

```
def test_add(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        self.calculator.add('hello', 4)
```

When you use `assertRaises` this way you just write the code normally inside the `with` block. This means it's a more natural way to code, and also you aren't limited to just testing a single function call.

Answer (score 5):

I think that `self` is being provided, but that `assertRaises` is expecting you to list the arguments separately. Try:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.calculator.add, 'hello', 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the values this way:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.calculator.add, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```